# how to remove multiple css styles from an element.style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My application generates some inline styles. In certain point I need to remove the `height`, the `width` and the `max-width` styles.

I've located the element like this:

```
const elems = window.$('.myElements');
    window.$.each(elems, (index, value) => {
      if (value.id.startsWith('myPanel')) {
```

here I've tried this:

```
         window.$(value).css({height: '', maxWidth: '', width: ''});
```

and this:

```
         window.$(value)[0].style.height = '';
         window.$(value)[0].style.width = '';
         window.$(value)[0].style.maxWidth = '';
```

also this:

```
         window.$(value).css('height', '');             
         window.$(value).css('max-width', '');
         window.$(value).css('width', '');
      }
    });
```

and no matter what it always remove only the first element. What am I missing here?

Comment: So you're setting the const to elems, but then referring to it as elementos? And why would you not simply `elems.each(function(){...});`

Comment: @Snowmonkey, fixed now, I'm using identifiers in spanish, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a starts with selector, no need to do the loop

```js
  $('div[id^="myPanel"]').each( function () {

    $(this).css({
      height: Math.floor(Math.random()*200) + "px",
      width: Math.floor(Math.random()*200) + "px"
    });
  })

window.setTimeout( function () {
  $('div[id^="myPanel"]').css({
    height: '',
    maxWidth: '',
    width: ''
  });}
, 1000);
```

```css
div {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myPanel1" style="width:20px; height: 20px;">A</div>
<div id="myPanel2" style="width:20px; height: 20px;">B</div>
<div id="myPanel3" style="width:20px; height: 20px;">C</div>
<div id="myPanel4" style="width:20px; height: 20px;">D</div>
```

Comment: your solution simplies my code, but still it only removes the first element.

Comment: Than I need to see some markup since it clearly works above. You have something else different. What is the HTML of the elements you are removing?

Comment: My styles are being generated... If I locate the style in the browsers Elements and remove it manually then it works

Comment: No clue what that means.

Comment: I mean: I'm testing jqwidgets for react, those components generate their styles in-line, then I need to remove those styles from a tree. When the page loads I go to the browser's inspector and locate manually these styles and remove them. then it works

Comment: @assembler Maybe your code is running before React generates the styles.

Comment: So sounds like if you remove them and they come back, that something is resetting the values. Maybe the react code is running and setting them again. Not knowing how your whole thing works makes it rather hard to actually help you. Since the above works, than that most likely means there is something else at play. Seems weird you are not reseting the model in react, but doing it with jQuery.

Comment: I don't like the way React handles the DOM elements, that is why I'm doing it with jQuery